# Is there a bounded function, holomorphic in $\{z : |z| < 1\}$ that does not extend to a function holomorphic on $\{z : |z| \le 1\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is holomorphic in $\{z : |z| < 1 \}$. It also has the property that $\forall z,|f(z)| < 1$. Does it extend to a function holomorphic on $\{z : |z| \le 1 \}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, $$f(z) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2^n}}{n^2}$$
has the unit circle as a natural boundary, and thus does not have any analytic continuation outside the open unit disk.  See the [Ostrowski-Hadamard gap theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%E2%80%93Hadamard_gap_theorem).